# INDEX-MATCH formula returns the same value in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

**What I'm trying to achieve?**

Use INDEX-MATCH formula to retrieve the PostCode by matching the Suburb in col F (Lugs tab) with the Suburb in col H (Config tab) and return the corresponding Post Code in Col I

**What is the issue?**

The INDEX-MATCH formula in cel `BA` (Lugs tab) returns the same Post code even though the suburbs are different.

```
={"Post Code Pickup";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(F2:F)," ", INDEX( Config!A2:I, MATCH(F2:F, Config!H2:H,0),9)))}
```

I have tested that the MATCH formula works correctly as it returns the correct row number in col BB (Lugs tab) eg; 240, 226, 147 etc.

```
={"Post Code Row #";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(F2:F),"", MATCH(F2:F, Config!H2:H,0)))}
```

`Lugs` tab data:

[image]

`Config` tab unsorted data is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Can you share a copy of your spreadsheet? That would make it a lot easier to help you out.

Comment: the two screenshots I pasted is it. I would have to desanitized the spreadsheet as it contains sensitive data. Are the formulas I pasted no enough?

Comment: Why do you have 9 after the match function ?

Comment: @MariosKaramanis `9` is the offset column to return eg; col 'I' Postcode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this works

```
={"Post Code Pickup"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(F2:F),, VLOOKUP(F2:F, Config!H2:I, 2, 0 )))}
```

Comment: This does work, although it does defeat the purpose of the question in addressing the INDEX-MATCH formula issue. As I understand it using INDEX-MATCH is way more efficient than a VLOOKUP, any ideas what the issue is in the current INDEX-MATCH formula?

Comment: The INDEX function does not support "iteration" over an array if an array is used as one of its arguments. So, it looks to me that VLOOKUP would be the way to go here.

Comment: @Roggie That may be the case in excel, but not in Google sheets.